# Display order of objects in vector in R

Tags: r

Let's say I create a simple vector:

`x <- seq(1, 50, by = 5)`

Then I might want to display its contents to see which item is the 7th:

```
print(x)

[1]  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
```

Is there a simple way to display the contents such that each item is numbered?

`[1] 1, [2] 6, [3] 11, etc.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple option is to column-bind a counter next to the original vector:

```
cbind(1:length(x), x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're asking how to modify `print` to include the index of every element of a vector `x`.

Here is a possibility

```
x <- seq(1, 50, by = 5)

cat(sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) (sprintf("[%i] %i", i, x[i]))), "\n")
#[1] 1 [2] 6 [3] 11 [4] 16 [5] 21 [6] 26 [7] 31 [8] 36 [9] 41 [10] 46
```

Or you could define a custom `my.print` function that nicely wraps lines every `nmax`th entry for long vectors

```
my.print <- function(x, nmax = 6) {
    os <- 0
    while (length(x) > 0) {
        cat(sapply(seq_along(x[1:min(length(x), 6)]), function(i)
            sprintf("[%i] %i", i + os, x[i])), "\n")
        x <- x[-(1:min(length(x), nmax))]
        os <- os + nmax
}}    

my.print(x)
#[1] 1 [2] 6 [3] 11 [4] 16 [5] 21 [6] 26
#[7] 31 [8] 36 [9] 41 [10] 46
```

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way might be to use `?names`.

```
x <- seq(1, 50, by = 5)
names(x) <- seq_along(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
```